# Prisma can a one to many relationship be created from a relation table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, prisma

I am creating a workout app using Prisma and MySQL.

I have a many to many relationship between a user and a prescribed program, shown in the model 'ProgramEnrollment'. The isssue I am having is I would like the user to log their personal workout sets.

My thoughts were to create a new model 'LoggedWorkoutSet' and then connect it to the model 'ProgramEnrollment' via a one to many relationship, meaning one 'ProgramEnrollment' can have many 'LoggedWorkoutSet'. This doesn't seem to be working for me, the issue is with when trying to define the relationship here:

```
program   ProgramEnrollment @relation(fields: [programId], references: [id])
  programId Int // relation scalar field  (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
```

The error I am getting is 'Error validating: The argument `references` must refer only to existing fields in the related model `ProgramEnrollment`. The following fields do not exist in the related model: id'

I'm not sure what to do, any help would be much appreciated.

```
model ProgramEnrollment {
  program                 Program     @relation(fields: [programId], references: [id])
  programId               Int // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  user                    User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId                  Int // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  assignedAt              DateTime @default(now())

  loggedWorkoutSet        LoggedWorkoutSet[]

  @@id([programId, userId])
}
```

```
model LoggedWorkoutSet {
  id              Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  reps            Int
  weight          Int
  completed       Boolean     @default(false)

  author   ProgramEnrollment @relation(fields: [programId], references: [id])
  programId Int // relation scalar field  (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think off is creating another model, for example 'LoggedProgram', then create a many to many relationship between 'LoggedProgram' and 'ProgramEnrollment', then create a one to many relatioship between between 'LoggedProgram' and 'LoggedWorkout'.

Comment: Is your data really 1:many instead of many:many?

Comment: Sorry James, I don't quite understand what you mean. The user can complete many programs, so that would be a many to many relationship. Do you mean the relationship between the 'Program' and the 'LoggedSet' tables, if so your right, that would be a one to many relationship. Does that mean it doesn't need to connect to the 'ProgramEnrollment' table? Should it just connect to a 'Sets' (schema not shown above) table via a one to one relationship?

Comment: "The user can complete many programs, so that would be a many to many" - Only if other users can complete the same program.  I can help with the SQL; I know nothing about Prisma.

Comment: Thanks Rick, appreciate your reply. No worries at all, no Prisma knowledge necessary, it's the SQL design i'm struggling to wrap my head around. Yes exactly it's many to many as all users can complete the same program. For example, I have a program called 'Get Jacked', I will prescribe this program, meaning write all the workouts, then any user that chooses to completed this program as many times as they like. The part I'm struggling with is how can they store their individual data (for example weight lifted and reps) for each time they choose to complete the program. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    user_id ...,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Programs (
    pgm_id ...,
    part_of_body ... -- legs/shoulders/...
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (pgm_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- Many-to-many, with stats:
CREATE TABLE UserPgm (
    user_id ...,
    pgm_id ...,
    latest_date DATE ...,
    reps SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    weight SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- in the normal units for this device
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, pgm_id),
    INDEX(pgm_id, user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

A query using all 3 tables:

```
-- The latest workout for a user:
SELECT u.name,
       up.latest_date,
       up.reps,
       p.device_name
    FROM Users    AS u
    JOIN UserPgm  AS up  USING(user_id)
    JOIN Programs AS p   USING(pgm_id)
    WHERE user_id = 123
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Rick. Because the user had multiple workouts and multiple sets, would it be wise to create a 'UserWorkout' table and 'UserSets' table to avoid creating excessive columns in the 'UserPgm' table?

Comment: @adherb - Probably.  Think through the relationships 1:many vs many:many.